# How to build a new range using multiple ranges in a specific order?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel table ranged from A to E columns with 50 rows. Row 1 is the header of table. I want to define a Range object that contains C2:C50 and B2:B50 with this order. It means that final object needs to be a matrix of 2x49 that first column is made from  data in C and second column from B. I used the following commands, but it still returns the data in the same order as it is in the reference table. (first B, second C). Anyone has any idea?

```
Set rng1 = Sheets("Sheets1").Range("C2:C50") 
Set rng2 = Sheets("Sheets1").Range("B2:B50") 

Set rng = Range(rng1.Address & "," & rng2.Address)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Application.Union method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.union) to combine 2 ranges:

```
Set rng = Application.Union(rng1, rng2)
```

A combination of ranges does not have any order. If you want to re-arrange the ranges you will need to do that on the worksheet itself or read the data into an array (in the order you want to have them).

Comment: It does not work. I plot the new built up range in a chart. But it shows that the data order does not change. `chrt.SetSourceData Source:=rng`

Comment: @Hamtash I told you if you want to change the order you will need to change the order in the worksheet itself. Ranges in VBA are just virtual pointers to the range of the worksheet. You cannot re-order it without moving the ranges in the sheet.